# How do I use Data Binding with XAML Apps, MVVM & JSON Sample Data?

Tags: xaml, data-binding, win-universal-app

The Universal App template has sample data in JSON and a SampleDataSource that loads that JSON file and provides a model. This is nice but I'm using MVVM and I need the PropertyChange Notifications.
My aim is this

DesignTime

- Load Sample Data from a json file (my webservice provides data in JSON so this is super helpful)
- Display the sample data in my UI

RunTime

- Load JSON (well PBF really) data from my live webservice
- Display Real Data in my UI

I'm struggling to understand how the databinding is meant to work in design time.
Should I have code to load and process the JSON into a model?
My JSON converts into my DataModel not my ViewModel, is this supported in the SampleData   infrastructure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've decided against using the JSON approach since the model conversion is so basic as to be worthless in a real application.
You essentially have to have a JSON file that maps precisely to the model with no exceptions which requires a very trivial model.
I'm going back to XAML :(